# Reading subject from outlook and writing into csv

Tags: javascript

I want to make sample, but I dont understand what I need to do...
Heres what I want (Excel):

[image]

And heres what I have:

[image]

```js
const {ImapFlow} = require ('imapflow');
const fs = require ("fs").promises;

// exchange webservice (MAPI)
const imap = new ImapFlow({
    host: "outlook.office365.com", //imap-mail.outlook.com  smtp.office365.com pop-mail.outlook.com
    port:  993, // 993 - imap,  587 - smtp. 995 - pop
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "pug**y@outlook.com",
      pass: "****",     
    }    
    
  });
  async function test (){
    const days =["","Понедельник", "Вторник","Среда","Четверг","Пятница","Суббота","Воскресенье"]
    let env=[];
    let myStr='';
    let dat = [];
    let subject= [];
    let dayOfWeek=[];
    let hours = [];
    let minutes = [];
    let month = [];
    await imap.connect();
    let lock = await imap.mailboxOpen('INBOX'); //SENT  
    for await (let msgs of imap.fetch('1:*', {envelope:true})){
        env.push (msgs.envelope)
        // console.log(msgs.envelope);   
    }
    await imap.logout();

    for await (let data of env){  
        if (data.subject === 'Приход в офис' || data.subject === 'Уход'){
            let myDate = data.date;
            dat.push(myDate.getDate());
            dayOfWeek.push(days[myDate.getDay()]);
            subject.push(data.subject);
            hours.push(myDate.getHours());
            minutes.push(myDate.getMinutes());
            month.push(myDate.getMonth()+1)
        } 
           
    }
    let myFile = ''
    for (let i=0;i<subject.length;i++){
        myStr = `${subject[i]}` + '\n' + ` ${dat[i]}` + `.${month[i]}.` + ` ${dayOfWeek[i]}` + ` ${hours[i]}` + ':' + `${minutes[i]}` + '\n';
        myFile +=myStr; 
    } 

    await fs.writeFile("mail.txt", myFile, (error)=>{ 
        if(error) throw error; 
        console.log("Асинхронная запись файла завершена. Содержимое файла:");
    });
    }   
test ();
```

What I need to do ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Your current state is a .txt file, but your goal is an excel file. Or do you want to create a CSV file?

Comment: First off all I need to make csv and after excel, but I did wrong csv....I think I need array of object, like [{date:..,arrive:...leave:...}], sort this array and after write in csv...but mb im wrong...